# Как реализовать круг с блуром?

Tags: html, css

проблема именно в блуре..]]]]]
[image: проблема именно в блуре]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте свойство filter: [blur()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur)

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #0000FF;
  filter: blur(3rem);
  opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Используй `filter: blur(10px)` или же `backdrop-filter: blur(10px)`